# Get 5 most frequent values/occuring ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the 5 most occurring IDs in my table, my table looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
| mashup_id | mashup_time         | user_id | deal_id |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|         1 | 2011-08-24 21:58:22 |       1 |   23870 |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

I was thinking of doing a query with a sub-query, something that orders by the count of deal_id? Not exactly sure how to go about it though, if anyone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In (sort of) generic SQL:

```
SELECT deal_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY deal_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

If you meant a different ID field, just substitute it for `deal_id`.

Comment: Not so generic, since your syntax is SQL Server's and not MySQL's! MySQL do indeed use LIMIT, not TOP.

Comment: This worked: 
select * from table group by deal_id order by count(*) desc limit 5;

Comment: @Vincent, yes, thanks.  I've checked that and corrected the answer. (And learned something.)

Comment: @John Salio : It works because MySQL is far, far away from standards. Use harpo's query.

Comment: i have just checked your query because i did not believe it works, I got an error and I returned to give -1 but as I can see you have correct the answer ;-) +1 instead

Comment: I'm guessing the DB is smart enough to re-use the first `COUNT(*)` in the `ORDER BY` clause however you can alias the aggregate function and re-use that alias for clarity, eg `SELECT deal_id, COUNT(*) AS foo ... ORDER BY foo DESC`

Comment: Also, there is no generic way to limit a result-set. Each DBMS has it's own way of doing this (Oracle being the worst of the bunch)

Comment: @Phil, that's why I said "sort of" generic.  And I used to favor aliasing in the way that you describe, but SQL Server sometimes complains about such references in a GROUP BY, whereas this method always works.  Any DMBS that can't optimize accordingly is not really a player.