# sort sold table by most frequent product_id

Tags: mysql, sorting

hi i have a sold table in my db , my table looks like this :

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+ 
| id        | product_id          | user_id | date    |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|         1 | 20                  |      2  |392185767| 
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|         2 | 28                  |      3  |392333337| 
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

i want to want to sort table output by most purchased products
something like :

```
$sql = "select * from sold order by most_repeated(product_id)";
```

i don't want to group the out put by product id , i just want to sort them so the most repeated products shows at the top of result

Comment: That questions has already been replied: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198671/get-5-most-frequent-values-occuring-ids

Comment: @EmilStenström This time the OP does not want to group by

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Are you saying the OP wants repeated product ID:s? I don't think so. Then grouping is the right thing to do.

Comment: @EmilStenström I think the post is very clear about that: "I don't want to group the output by product_id".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not want to group by, you could use a correlated query:

```
select * from sold s
order by (select COUNT(1) from sold ss where ss.product_id=s.product_id)
```

I have not tried this in MySQL, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot find the repeated products without counting it.

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) AS product_count
FROM sold
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY product_count DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you what you want without having to count the same product multiple times.

```
    select s.* 
       from sold s join
        (select count(product_id) as times_purchased, product_id
           from sold
          group by product_id)   most_repeated on s.product_id = most_repeated.product_id
   order by most_repeated.times_purchased
```

Good Luck!